# How to add missing seconds to a datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a datetime object `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)` The object doesn't have seconds field. How can I add zero (00) seconds to it so the object becomes `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50, 00)`.

Comment: Why do you want that? This doesn't make any sense. The datetime object stores the seconds, it just doesn't show them in its representation when the seconds are zero. See `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50).second == 0`

Comment: I have a lot of data with date format that also includes seconds. I might need to increase the date by seconds later on. That's why. Do you know how make the datetime object show it in it's representation?

Comment: You can increase it by seconds even if it doesn't show them. It is impossible to make the object show it in it's representation, but you can print them as a string: `"datetime.datetime({d.year}, {d.month}, {d.day}, {d.hour}, {d.minute}, {d.second})".format(d=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50))`

Comment: @L3viathan my usecase is that I'm getting a datetime from a form that doesn't include seconds, and when converting to isodate(), the resulting string doesn't include them, and causing the Django DatetimeField to throw a validation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` only shows seconds in its output if seconds are not 0.

You can confirm this by doing:

```
x = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)
x.second
# 0
x = x.replace(second=45)
# datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50, 45)
```

Comment: I would like to see x as `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50,00)` `x = x.replace(second=00)` still gives me `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)`

Comment: If you want a particular output format, then `datetime.strftime` is your friend - e.g. : `x.strftime('%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
a = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(seconds=00)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)
>>> print("datetime.datetime({d.year}, {d.month}, {d.day}, {d.hour}, {d.minute}, {d.second})".format(d=d))
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50, 0)
```

I still don't see why you would want this though.

Comment: yes, you are right. Just using pd.date_range() on a datetime object like this `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 23, 50)`  also shows the seconds.